# How to flatten a table from row to columns

Tags: sql, merge, pivot, mariadb, mariadb-10.2

I use MariaDB 10.2.21
I have not seen this exact case elsewhere, hence my request for assistance.

I have a History table containing one record per change on any of the fields in a JIRA issues:

```
+----------+---------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+
| IssueKey | OriginalValue | NewValue |      Field      |     ChangeDate      |
+----------+---------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+
| HRSK-184 | (NULL)        |        2 | Risk Detection  | 2019-10-24 10:57:27 |
| HRSK-184 | (NULL)        |        2 | Risk Occurrence | 2019-10-24 10:57:27 |
| HRSK-184 | (NULL)        |        2 | Risk Severity   | 2019-10-24 10:57:27 |
| HRSK-184 | 2             |        4 | Risk Detection  | 2019-10-25 11:54:07 |
| HRSK-184 | 2             |        6 | Risk Detection  | 2019-10-25 11:54:07 |
| HRSK-184 | 2             |        3 | Risk Severity   | 2019-10-24 11:54:07 |
| HRSK-184 | 6             |        5 | Risk Detection  | 2019-10-26 09:11:01 |
+----------+---------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Every record contains the old and new value and the fieldtype that has changed ('Field') and, of course, the corresponding timestamp of that change.

I want to query the point-in-time status providing me the **combination of the most recent values** of every of the fields 'Risk Severity, Risk Occurrence and Risk Detection'.

The result should be like this:

```
+----------+----------------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+
| IssueKey | Risk Severity  |  Risk Occurrence  |  Risk Detection  |  ChangeDate          |
+----------+----------------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+
| HRSK-184 | 3              |  2                |  5               |  2019-10-26 09:11:01 |
+----------+----------------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+
```

Any ideas? I'm stuck...
Thanks in advance for you effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cold use a couple of inline queries

```
select 
    IssueKey,
    (
        select t1.NewValue 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.IssueKey = t.IssueKey and t1.Field = 'Risk Severity'
        order by ChangeDate desc limit 1
    ) `Risk Severity`,
    (
        select t1.NewValue 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.IssueKey = t.IssueKey and t1.Field = 'Risk Occurrence'
        order by ChangeDate desc limit 1
    ) `Risk Occurrence`,
    (
        select t1.NewValue 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.IssueKey = t.IssueKey and t1.Field = 'Risk Detection'
        order by ChangeDate desc limit 1
    ) `Risk Severity`,
    max(ChangeDate) ChangeDate
from mytable t
group by IssueKey
```

With an index on `(IssueKey, Field, ChangeDate, NewValue)`, this should an efficient option.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f919bb53e5c6add3dae391980b58ba80)**:

```
IssueKey | Risk Severity | Risk Occurrence | Risk Severity | ChangeDate     
:------- | ------------: | --------------: | ------------: | :------------------
HRSK-184 |             3 |               2 |             5 | 2019-10-26 09:11:01
```

Comment: This is indeed what I am looking for. I will tune&twek a little more. Thank you @GMB!

Answer (score 1):

`MariaDB 10.2` has introduced some `Window Functions` for analytical queries.

One of them is `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ...ORDER BY...)` function.

Firstly, you can apply it, and then pivot through `Conditional Aggregation` :

```
SELECT IssueKey,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = 'Risk Severity'   THEN NewValue END ) AS RiskSeverity,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = 'Risk Occurrence' THEN NewValue END ) AS RiskOccurrence,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = 'Risk Detection'  THEN NewValue END ) AS RiskDetection,
       MAX(ChangeDate) AS ChangeDate
  FROM
  (
   SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY IssueKey, Field ORDER BY ChangeDate Desc) rnk,
          t.*
     FROM mytable t 
  ) t
  WHERE rnk = 1
  GROUP BY IssueKey;

IssueKey | RiskSeverity  | RiskOccurrence  | RiskDetection  | ChangeDate     
-------- + --------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------------
HRSK-184 |             3 |               2 |              5 | 2019-10-26 09:11:01
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d37a0241bb174c455bba65a770750253)</kbd>